# Visual Studio, find/replace text within all files inside a certain Filter (of Solution Explorer)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

*After searching about 1 month, I still don't find how to do it.*

I am using Visual Studio 2015, and create a lot of filter in Solution Explorer.

- All of my .cpp and .h, are in the same Windows folder, but in different Visual Studio's filter.

I want to replace all words of all files within a certain filter

- e.g. replace all occurrences of "CustomArray()" by "CA".

I don't want that action to take effect on the whole project.

I tried :-

```
Edit > find in file
```

But I didn't find any option to limit the affect to only a certain filter.

Is there any way to achieve it?

### **Edit**

I want it to affect all files inside a FILTER.

I don't want a solution that affect all files inside the WINDOW folder.

### **Example**

The whole project consists of files f1.h, f2.h, and f3.h.

They are all inside **C:/Fs** (without subdirectory), but only f1.h & f2.h are inside a **a_filter_name** FILTER.

I want a one-pop-up solution of "replace all" that affect only f1.h & f2.h.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to happen. You *don't* want it to affect the whole project, and you *don't* want it to affect all the files in the same Windows folder. So what *do* you want it to affect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close all files, then open all files from the filter (select all of them with Shift+Click, like in Windows Explorer, and press Enter), then in search form use the option "All Open Documents".

Comment: Nice trick.  What if a filter has sub-filter?  They are all collapsed.  I don't know any trick to let the filter expand all.

Comment: Key `*` (asterisk) from numeric keyboard does that. Both in Windows Explorer (just one more level) and Visual Studio (complete tree).